# EF Code First and indicating a simple foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, entity-framework-6

Let's say I have an entity `EntityA` with two unique columns, `Key1` and `Key2`. At the moment only `Key1` is the PK.

Now I want another entity named `EntityB`, to have a FK from `EntityB.AKey2` to `EntityA.Key2`. I don't need a navigation property from one to the other, just to limit the values on `EntityB.AKey2` to the values in `EntityA.Key2`.

However, I cannot find the way of doing this mapping.

Update: I do not mind to have a navigation property, as long I can indicate that is pointing to the `Key2` column and not to `Key1`.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without a navigation property. Edit: actually you can try only adding the FK (although with a nav prop) to EntityA, but not EntityB.

Comment: I don't mind to have a navigation property. I don't need it, but it is not a problem to have it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I've searched around but it appears that EF does not support this behavior currently. You can vote [here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/299) to try to help it along.

Comment: Too bad. There were a way of executing SQL during the model creation, but I don't remember where. Rings any bell? I may be able of executing a statement to set the FK. Not ideal, but something...

Comment: if you're using migrations you can call Sql(string sql) and pass it a script as a string.